# how to stop getting encoding popup on every file open in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Why I am getting this popup every time I open any file in visual studio-15. and how to stop getting this encoding popup and open file in default editor.
Thank you.

[image: screen shot of popup]

Answer (score 4):

Does this happen with any file type you attempt to open in VS, or just .cs files?

If only .cs files, then it's possible that the default "viewer" for .cs files got set to "CSharp Editor with Encoding."  To check this, click Open File in VS, navigate to a .cs file, and instead of clicking the Open button, click the split dropdown button next to the Open button and select Open With...  Choose "CSharp Editor (Default)" and then click the Set as Default button. Theoretically, that should fix the problem.

If this problem occurs with all file types, however, then I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: you will refer this link:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx